# Evaluate $ \int \frac{\tan(x)}{2+\sin(x)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How do you evalute this integral?
$$
\int \frac{\tan(x)}{2+\sin(x)}dx
$$

Comment: There may be a slicker way, but the Weierstrass substitution $x = 2 \arctan t$ will transform this into an integral with rational integrand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x(2+\sin x)}=\frac{\sin x+2-2}{\cos x(2+\sin x)}$$

$$=\sec x-2\cdot\frac{\cos x}{(1-\sin^2x)(2+\sin x)}$$

For the second integral, set $\sin x=u$

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{(1-\sin^2x)(2+\sin x)}dx=\int\frac1{(1-u)(1+u)(2+u)}du$$

**Method**$\#1:$ Now use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

**Method**$\#2:$  $\dfrac1{(1-u)(1+u)(2+u)}=\dfrac{2+u-(1+u)}{(1-u)(1+u)(2+u)}$

$=\dfrac1{(1-u)(1+u)}-\dfrac1{(1-u)(2+u)}$

Again $\dfrac1{(1-u)(1+u)}=\dfrac12\dfrac{1-u+1+u}{(1-u)(1+u)}=$

and $\dfrac1{(1-u)(2+u)}=?$

Comment: What you did with $\cos{x}$ after the $u=\sin{x}$ substitution?

Comment: @PeterHorvath, $$\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: OMG! :-) Thank you! :-)

Comment: well when he changed dx to du, it was actually 
$$
dx = \frac{du}{cos(x)}
$$

@lab bhattacharjee
Thank you for the answer